# How to get the count of all the test cases in my Maven Selenium test project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven, intellij

At the moment I'm working on a legacy Maven Selenium test project.
It will take around 10 hours to run the entire test suite.
After 10 hours from the IntelliJ I can get the total number of test cases which get executed, apart from that is there any way to get the total number of test cases in my project?

Answer (score 1):

You can run Maven in dry run mode, so it will perform the maven test lifecycle, but without executing the tests:

```
mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true
```

Then you can pipe the output into [grep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-3i42XXzek) to look for the pattern that contains the info you are looking for.